# Is my number a de Polignac number?

Tags: code-golf, number, number-theory, decision-problem

A number is a de Polignac number if and only if it is **odd** and *cannot* be represented in the form **p + 2<sup>n</sup>** where **n** is a non-negative integer and **p** is a prime integer.

## Task

Write some code that takes a positive integer and determines if it is a de Polignac number.  You may output two distinct values one for true and one for false.  You should aim to minimize your byte count.

## Test Cases

[For positive cases here's the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A006285)

```
1, 127, 149, 251, 331, 337, 373, 509, 599, 701, 757, 809, 877, 905, 907, 959, 977, 997, 1019, 1087, 1199, 1207, 1211, 1243, 1259, 1271, 1477, 1529, 1541, 1549, 1589, 1597, 1619, 1649, 1657, 1719, 1759, 1777, 1783, 1807, 1829, 1859, 1867, 1927, 1969, 1973, ...
```

Here are some negative cases:

```
22, 57
```

Comment: Can we have truthy and falsy outputs instead of two distinct outputs?

Comment: @Okx I'm going to say no.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61371/discussion-between-einkorn-enchanter-and-leaky-nun).

Comment: Err... for the negative cases, it's basically any number not in the OEIS right? Making sure I've not missed something obvious.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn Yes.

Answer (score 11):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>9</s> <s>14</s> 13 bytes

```
o!²mnU dj |Uv
```

[Test it online!](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=byGybW5VIGRqIHxVdg==&input=MTI3) or [Find all de Polignac integers under 1000](http://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=MTAwMG8gZlV7IShVdiCqVW8hsm1uVSBkag==&input=).

Outputs `1` for falsy inputs and `0` for truthy.

#### Explanation

```
 o!²  mnU dj |Uv
Uo!p2 mnU dj |Uv  : Ungolfed
                  : Implicit: U = input integer (e.g. 9)
Uo                : Create the range [0..U), and map each item X to
  !p2             :   2 ** X.               [1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128, 256]
      m           : Map each of these powers of 2 by
       nU         :   subtracting from U.   [8, 7, 5, 1, -7, -23, -57, -119, -247]
          d       : Return whether any item in the result is
           j      :   prime.                (5 and 7 are, so `true`)
             |    : Take the bitwise OR of this and
              Uv  :   U is divisble by (missing argument = 2).
                  : This gives 1 if U cannot be represented as p + 2^n or if U is even.
                  : Implicit: output result of last expression
```

Comment: This seems to be giving the wrong results for 2 & 3; it's returning `false` but they're not de Polignac numbers.

Comment: @Shaggy `3` is fixed, but we didn't have to handle even cases at first. Fixing.

Comment: @Shaggy Fixed now.

Comment: I was about to say it was a good thing the fix for `3` didn't cost any bytes then I saw the fix for `2` - Ouch!

Comment: :O +1 for competitive program that doesn't look like encoding error

Answer (score 8):

## JavaScript (ES6),  <s>56 54</s>  53 bytes

Returns \$0\$ or \$1\$.

```js
f=(n,p=1,x=y=n-p)=>n>p?y%--x?f(n,p,x):x!=1&f(n,p*2):n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYyxDsIgFEX3fgUOGp4ppHVs8tq4OujgaByaCg1KHgQaA1@PreM95@S@x@8Yp2D8Isi9VCkaOdUe2zphRhIesKfeD3kvRBr05uoEXdphe/iv4wk6KpOj6KyS1s28Yuxyv11lXIKh2ei8EcYeUspzCGPmbdM0ID8qRw5PqY1dVODEsGfrI8BaQwXlBw)

#### How?

We start with \$p = 1\$. We test whether \$y = n - p\$ is composite and yield a boolean accordingly. The next test is performed with \$p \times 2\$.

As soon as \$p\$ is greater than \$n\$, we stop the recursion and return \$n\$.

The results of all iterations are AND'd together, coercing the boolean values to either \$0\$ or \$1\$.

Provided that all intermediate results were truthy, we end up with a bitwise test such as:

`1 & 1 & 1 & n`

This gives \$1\$ if and only if \$n\$ is odd, which is the last condition required to validate the input as a de Polignac number.

Comment: Great technique. Probably the only valid answer that doesn't explicitly say `n%2` or similar :P

Comment: This has false negatives for de Polignac numbers of the form 2^M+1, such as 262145 and 2097153 (subsequent ones are 4722366482869645213697, 38685626227668133590597633, 5192296858534827628530496329220097, etc.). It's not the largeness of the numbers that's a problem, since it correctly identifies 262139, 262259, 2097131, and 2097187, for example. Of course due to the recursion, I had to enlarge the stack size to something very huge to test this, and only tested the ranges around the first two 2^M+1 de Polignac numbers listed above.

Comment: @Deadcode Thanks for reporting this. Now fixed.

Comment: @Arnauld I don't think that fixes it. I haven't managed to get it to run in JavaScript with an increased stack size, but when I [apply your patch to my C port of your function](https://tio.run/##fVDRSsMwFH3vV1wnK4lLp61McF07xKcxfdE9CmWk6Qx2aUhSaR399tqkE8QH78PJ5Zx7Ty6HShkcKO17LgwUyKIgFqXDxmGLT4qZWgkQqVyjJg19v50GQYPXBRJEkoaIQOJlc5GEvmOuIsv8IF6KuOsvuaBlnTNYaZPzav6eer@oVl8rpqtaUWYV77PiOWhmMm329CPT/Ish7J08GEobVVMDquRHbp/YsQdmRga9PG2eN7vsdffwuCXgqxKPE6qc24mM1goSiBY3Y42i/ne98zybxHHPxfmMv7dZl6JS4DLkSXQXhbf3MfCVbaOFbWcz7L7iBaAhawIhAR6MgEcJQKrBoECTaf4mJoPkjM/xD6d2/Tc), it still has the bug.

Comment: @Deadcode I think a correct port would be [this one](https://tio.run/##fVDRSsMwFH3vV1wnK4lLp61McF07xKcxfdE9CmWk6Qx2aUhSaR399tqkE8QH78PJ5Zx7Ty6HShkcKO17LgwUyKIgFqXDxmGLT4qZWgkQqVyjJgjS0PfbaYPXBRJEkoaIQOJlc5GEvmOuIsv8IF6KuOsvuaBlnTNYaZPzav6eer@oVl8rpqtaUWYV77PiOWhmMm329CPT/Ish7J08GEobVVMDquRHbp/YsQdmRga9PG2eN7vsdffwuCXgqxKPE6qc24mM1goSiBY3Y42i/ne98zybxHHPxfmMv7dZl6JS4DLkSXQXhbf3MfCVbaOFbWcz7L7iBaAhawIhAR6MgEcJQKrBoECTaf4mJoPkjM/xD6d2/Tc).

Comment: @Arnauld Ah, you're right :) Just to be certain, I [did this](https://tio.run/##fVHRToMwFH3nK@5mtlBX5sDMxDG2GJ8W9UX3aEKglNkIpWmLYS58O9KyJcYH78PpzTmnpze3RAjvQEjXMa5BJTktq8w1fYINpugkqa4lH6XbxSqZpGHrGD63Hm49wmJj8XjxA9@I7SXviD2vQdvc5VjgBnNPoFUzivypZa4Dw1wQrXjYdleMk6LOKKyVzlg1/9g4v6ijupFUVbUk1CjOV8UyUFTHSifkM1bsm7rIOTnQl9KyJhpkwUpmjtCyB6oHxn193r3s9vHb/uHxCcNUFmhwyGJuHDGpJUQQLBdDDaL693rr2B2VCePnMf7OZlLySoLdIouCu8C/vQ@BrU0bLE07myH7FMvB7beNwcfAvAHQIAEI2Qfk7niSvfNxL9ng8wf0o7bdDw) and sure enough, it's fixed.

Comment: I finally figured out how to [test this properly](https://tio.run/##HY2xDoIwFAB3vqImaPqEmlLRRODBpKuDH0AQqTZiSywmYPx3BLa73HDXwj4Gi2EYcs7jT61eqiXsYolLqWu9gIsQIKZl0SZJfjyf8kEi1X6Dgd9hj5o1gKlOm6xfMtZlcmp@B1G3wGA121pApB1p3oQqFHsRbA@xSiYSu5E8D4iShEqqAEhptDV1tanNffR4mJcO/LS5VYQx2xblM7fqW6Frhz8) :)

Comment: @Deadcode Neat! :)

Answer (score 8):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>11</s> 10 bytes

*Saved 1 byte thanks to @Dennis*

```
Ḷ2*³_ÆPS<Ḃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//4bi2MirCs1/DhlDCrDvhuILhuqD///8xMjc)

#### How it works

```
Ḷ2*³_ÆPS<Ḃ   Main link. Argument: n (integer)
Ḷ            Lowered range; yield [0, 1, 2, ..., n-1].
 2*          Reversed exponentiation with 2; yield [1, 2, 4, ..., 2**(n-1)].
   ³_        Reversed subtraction with the input; yield [n-1, n-2, n-4, ..., n-2**(n-1)].
     ÆP      Replace each item with 1 if it is prime, 0 otherwise.
       S     Sum; yield a positive integer if any item was prime, 0 otherwise.
         Ḃ   Yield n % 2.
        <    Yield 1 if the sum is less than n % 2, 0 otherwise.
             This yields 1 if and only if the sum is 0 and n is odd.
```

Comment: `Ḷ2*⁸_ÆPS<Ḃ`  saves a byte. https://tio.run/##ASQA2/9qZWxsef//4bi2Mirigbhfw4ZQUzzhuIL/MTAwMMOHw5BmWf8

Comment: @Dennis Thanks, I knew there had to be a 3-byte alternative to `¬;ḂẠ`. `S<Ḃ` is way outside the box though, at least for me :-)

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>9</s> 8 bytes

-1 byte thanks to Emigna

```
Ýo-pZ¹È~
```

Outputs `0` for truthy inputs and `1` for falsy inputs.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f//8Nx83YKoQzsPd9T9/29oZA4A)

Comment: `1å` could be `Z`.

Comment: @Emigna Ah. I knew there was a 1-byte alternative to that!

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), <s>60</s> <s>57</s> 56 bytes

```python
f=lambda n,k=1,p=-1:k/n or(n-k&n-k-p%k>0)&n&f(n,k+1,p*k)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcoxDgIhEEDRGk4xjQQUIlhuwp5lMC5K0IGwNJ6eZYtf/Vf//VPoMUb03/B7vgKQzt7p6o1b8p2gNEkmi5mpl7xaJUhEOdFtomtWI5YGBImgBXpv0mlw1lq1cBb2fWsdcHKFp5BoUQM6VJyzFOEc07HaEnWgcQA)

Comment: Wow, this is impressively inefficient. [Prime test via Wilson's theorem](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r//3@era6hNVdafpFCtkJmnkJRYl56qoahjoKpgaYVl0JBUWZeiUK2jkKeKojgUsjTss22/g8A). On the plus side it works correctly for 262145 and 2097153 (assuming unlimited stack and bignum size); some of the other submissions don't. Its is-prime algorithm yields "truthy" for 4, because (-6)%4=2, but this ends up not being a problem because even numbers are rejected by the `&n&`. The number 5 would be a false negative if it were a de Polignac number, because 1+4=5, but this isn't a problem because 2+3=5 anyway.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

*An alternative 10-byte Jelly submission to the one already posted.*

```
_ÆRBS€’×ḂẠ
```

A monadic link returning **1** for de Polignac numbers and **0** otherwise.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//X8OGUkJT4oKs4oCZw5fhuILhuqD///8xMjc)** or see [those under 1000](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z/@cFuQU/CjpjWPGmYenv5wR9PDXQv@n9h@uB0oFPIfAA).

#### How?

```
_ÆRBS€’×ḂẠ - Link: number, n  e.g.  1    3      5                  6                   127
 ÆR        - prime range            []   [2]    [2,3,5]            [2,3,5]             [2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19,23,29,31,37,41,43,47,53,59,61,67,71,73,79,83,89,97,101,103,107,109,113,127]
_          - subtract from n        []   [1]    [3,2,0]            [4,3,1]             [125,124,122,120,116,114,110,108,104,98,96,90,86,84,80,74,68,66,60,56,54,48,44,38,30,26,24,20,18,14,0]
   B       - convert to binary      []   [[1]]  [[1,1],[1,0],[0]]  [[1,0,0],[1,1],[1]  [[1,1,1,1,1,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,1,0,1,0],[1,1,1,1,0,0,0],[1,1,1,0,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1,1,0,0],[1,1,0,1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1,1,0],[1,0,1,0,1,0,0],[1,0,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,0,1,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,1,0,0],[1,1,1,0,0,0],[1,1,0,1,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0,0],[1,0,1,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1,1,0],[1,1,1,1,0],[1,1,0,1,0],[1,1,0,0,0],[1,0,1,0,0],[1,0,0,1,0],[1,1,1,0],0]
    S€     - sum €ach               []   [1]    [2,1,0]            [1,2,1]             [6,5,5,4,4,4,5,4,3,3,2,4,4,3,2,3,2,2,4,3,4,2,3,3,4,3,2,2,2,3,0]
      ’    - decrement              []   [0]    [1,0,-1]           [0,1,0]             [5,4,4,3,3,3,4,3,2,2,1,3,3,2,1,2,1,1,3,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,1,1,1,2,-1]
        Ḃ  - n mod 2                1    1      1                  0                   1
       ×   - multiply               []   [0]    [1,0,-1]           [0,0,0]             [5,4,4,3,3,3,4,3,2,2,1,3,3,2,1,2,1,1,3,2,3,1,2,2,3,2,1,1,1,2,-1]
         Ạ - all truthy?            1    0      0                  0                   1
```

Comment: Took me about 10 minutes to understand how this works... great technique, I couldn't think of a good way to check if an array contained no powers of two :-)

Answer (score 6):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 99 bytes

```python
lambda n:n&1-any(n-2**k>1and all((n-2**k)%j for j in range(2,n-2**k))for k in range(len(bin(n))-2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RclBDoIwEAXQq8wGM0PsohN0YSInYTMEqoX6IQ0bTl80IXH73rpv7wVawrMryT79YIQHLt4ZdobTup5bbxjIUuITpJooLJkmiqBseI2s17PkF/M/0gjuIxgiTkXKmiM2Dqx39c3tCwc)

-4 bytes thanks to Leaky Nun

-2 bytes thanks to Wondercricket

+8 bytes to fix a mistake

-1 byte thanks to Mr. Xcoder

-3 bytes thanks to Einkorn Enchanter

+12 bytes to fix a mistake

Comment: I think this is also a Python 3 compatible answer?

Comment: This has a false negative for 1 and for all de Polignac numbers of the form 2^M+1, such as 262145 and 2097153 (subsequent ones are 4722366482869645213697, 38685626227668133590597633, 5192296858534827628530496329220097, etc.). It's not the largeness of the numbers that's a problem, since it correctly identifies 262139, 262259, 2097131, and 2097187, for example.

Comment: @Deadcode explicit check to make sure the "prime" isn't 1; should work now

Answer (score 6):

## Regex (ECMAScript), 97 bytes

This problem posed an interesting case for working around the problem of lacking non-atomic lookahead. And it's the only time so far that I've had a good reason to put both versions of the power of 2 test, `((x+)(?=\2$))*x$` and `(?!(x(xx)+)\1*$)`, in the same regex, and the only time so far I've needed to protect the prime test against matching 1, as `(?!(xx+)\1+$)xx`, when used in a larger regex.

`^(?!(xx)*$|(x+)((?!(xx+)\4+$).*(?=\2$)((x+)(?=\6$))*x$|(?!(x(xx)+)\7*$).*(?=\2$)(?!(xx+)\9+$)xx))`

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TY/LbsIwEEV/BaIIZpImJBGlKq5h1QUbFu2ytJIFJnFrHMs2kPL49tRRhcRuZs65Gt1vdmB2bYR2idViw82uVj/8tzVU8WPvjZevjQY40dkoar9g3oemwSi8QBMj/K8xrsZxiGkEc7oqQn/umJ8nIWLUeLfTupw3n6J785Z/9nnPsY1GJ0xd/e6MUCVgaqVYc5g8JGNEYmlGjpWQHEBSw9lGCsUBsU/VXko8l1SmVkvhYJgMkYgtgKJlKrkqXYWz4nIRdsmWIKhmxvKFclB@ZJ@IN8DvgZrl83zaYXSVqY/BQh2YFJueYark014QS7KtDRDxQjkRcYz@YdAEqeGaMwcC0x1z6woM4tkOBtpXctC1yIneO@uMV8j12mZJXjxmfw)

```
# For the purposes of these comments, the input number = N.
^
# Assert that N is not the sum of a prime number and a power of 2.
(?!
    (xx)*$                 # Assert that N is odd.
|
    # Since we must cycle through all values for a number X and a corresponding number
    # N-X, this cannot be in an atomic lookahead. The problem then becomes that it
    # consumes characters. Thus we must let X be the larger of the two and N-X be the
    # smaller, and do tests on X followed by tests on N-X. We can't just test X for
    # being prime and N-X for being a power of 2, nor vice versa, because either one
    # could be smaller or larger. Thus, we must test X for being either prime or a
    # power of 2, and if it matches as being one of those two, do the opposite test on
    # N-X.
    # Note that the prime test used below, of the form (?!(xx+)\2+$), has a false match
    # for 0 and 1 being prime. The 0 match is harmless for our purposes, because it
    # will only result in a match for N being a power of 2 itself, thus rejecting
    # powers of 2 as being de Polignac numbers, but since we already require that N is
    # odd, we're already rejecting powers of 2 implicitly. However, the 1 match would
    # break the robustness of this test. There can be de Polignac numbers of the form
    # 2^M+1, for example 262145 and 2097153. So we must discard the 1 match by changing
    # the prime test to "(?!(xx+)\2+$)xx". We only need to do this on the N-X test,
    # though, because as X is the larger number, it is already guaranteed not to be 1.
    (x+)           # \2 = N-X = Smaller number to test for being prime or a power of 2;
                   # tail = X = larger number to test for being prime or a power of 2.
    (
        (?!(xx+)\4+$)      # Test X for being prime.
        .*(?=\2$)          # tail = N-X
        ((x+)(?=\6$))*x$   # Test N-X for being a power of 2. Use the positive version
                           # since it's faster and doesn't have a false match of 0.
    |
        (?!(x(xx)+)\7*$)   # Test X for being a power of 2. Use the negative version
                           # because the testing of X has to be in a lookahead, and
                           # putting the positive version in a positive lookahead would
                           # be worse golf. It doesn't matter that this can have a false
                           # match of 0, because X is guaranteed never to be 0.
        .*(?=\2$)          # tail = N-X
        (?!(xx+)\9+$)xx    # Test N-X for being prime. We must prevent a false match of
                           # 1 for the reason described above.
    )
)
```

## Regex (ECMAScript + molecular lookahead), <s>53</s> 52 bytes

`^(?!(xx)*$|(?*xx+(((x+)(?=\4$))*x$))\2(?!(xx+)\5+$))`

```
# For the purposes of these comments, the input number = N.
^
# Assert that N is not the sum of a prime number and a power of 2.
(?!
    (xx)*$                   # Assert that N is odd.
|
    (?*
        xx+                  # Force N - \2 to be > 1, because the prime test used
                             # below has a false match of 1, which would otherwise
                             # give us false negatives on de Polignac numbers of the
                             # form 2^M+1, such as 262145 and 2097153.
        (((x+)(?=\4$))*x$)   # Cycle through subtracting all possible powers of 2 from
                             # tail, so we can then test {N - {power of 2}} for being
                             # prime.
                             # \2 = the power of 2
    )
    \2                       # tail = N - \2
    (?!(xx+)\5+$)            # Test tail for being prime. If it matches, this will fail
                             # the outside negative lookahead, showing that N is not a
                             # de Polignac number.
)
```

This version is not only much cleaner, but much faster, because instead of having to cycle through all possible ways that N is the sum of two numbers, it can just cycle through subtracting every power of 2 from N and test the difference for being prime.

The molecular lookahead can be easily converted to a variable-length lookbehind:

## Regex (.NET or ECMAScript 2018), <s>55</s> 54 bytes

`^(?!(xx)*$|xx+(((x+)(?=\4$))*x$)(?<=(?<!^\5+(x+x))\2))`

[Try it online! (.NET)](https://tio.run/##ZVBba9swFH7fr1BCIOfUF@ywC0xVOzB7KLR0LIU9LCtozmkqUGQjyZkap789U@y2LxUIJL7vnO9Su6xuLB2N3JJrZU1s@eQ8bfvOKbNhlaga4xpNfPzfUfD5T9p0WtrvobXknIoEXmvpHNv2zkuvarZr1JrdSGUYYL@TljnxbXq8h8sJhIBns0MICQCEBOFSrD7OEM/CLL7PRbyT@9WnJGIBcbVAPE75aYMVhv6xKE0BXL7s/jpvoyMoU5dfk9n4x2yB6YDftv5kKq@abas0rZGPXKb5Q2NBGc@MKDhoUcUscn2tDAHiRJhOa25Eib16AHNRYJX/ssrTSBhstELny1YrD/Nsjvy0S6XEP8SB9sXHxeJwmEQgv7NPP6R1BO3v4k/adJGK76HXsawcOYSvsjC9MjupY5VWmg19ZX3xPE01ctKOhlrDUMpybGIe5qnCt4j7GFGdC@IqSdKQiAhjdGnzK3cjff0Isd9Tzv27nHtR8jcLg2Z48Yj8eTjHIiu/fC7@Aw)
[Try it online! (ECMAScript 2018)](https://tio.run/##TY7BbsIwEER/BSIk7xJiJVG5JJiceuDCoT02RViJCVulTmobsAR8exoqVeKw0khvZna@5FnaylDvIt3VarAizo14U82r7@HdGdINN/KyH3ZQTMF7nM9u3ocA4EOEQpQvM8S5n416Jcab7splODKPWKaIw57blioFySJKEHOjfk5kFDCjZN2SVgx5NWqnNtopc5Cj9Uq6P7msN12lrOXW1aTvyDsN7C@xaMX62oiW274lByximNMBQIuGt0o37ojr9HYju5VbINFLYx/t0HzEn4j/QD0DvU6KJHtgdEfTXYKNPsuW6omRulHZJAjb/NAZyGklVE5hiOPDwAfcqH4cD4T8W7rqCAbx@jS8Ozl@MeQUgC1YqVnGGIaEuRVJfr/jEEdpuox/AQ)

```
# For the purposes of these comments, the input number = N.
^
# Assert that N is not the sum of a prime number and a power of 2.
(?!
    (xx)*$                 # Assert that N is odd.
|
    xx+                    # Force N - \2 to be > 1, because the prime test used
                           # below has a false match of 1, which would otherwise
                           # give us false negatives on de Polignac numbers of the
                           # form 2^M+1, such as 262145 and 2097153.
    (((x+)(?=\4$))*x$)     # Cycle through subtracting all possible powers of 2 from
                           # tail, so we can then test {N - {power of 2}} for being
                           # prime.
                           # \2 = the power of 2
    (?<=
        (?<!^\5+(x+x))     # Test tail for being prime. If it matches, this will fail
                           # the outside negative lookahead, showing that N is not a
                           # de Polignac number.
        \2                 # tail = N - \2
    )
)
```

Comment: Your regex can be optimised to `^(?!(x+)((?!(xx+)\3+$)x*(?!(x(xx)+)\4*$)|x(?!(x(xx)+)\6*$)x*(?!(xx+)\8+$)x)?\1$)` without too much difficulty. Then, with some careful thought, can be golfed further to `^(?!(x+)((x?)(?!(x(x\3)+)\4+$)x*(?!(x(xx)+|\3\3+)\6+$)\3)?\1$)`. Shorter may yet be possible

Comment: My shortest is very slow, though

Comment: oh, `(x(xx)+|\3\3+)` -> `(x\3?(xx)+)`

Answer (score 4):

## Mathematica, 41 bytes

```
OddQ@#&&!Or@@PrimeQ[#-2^Range[0,Log2@#]]&
```

Comment: There's no builtin for this? Wow, I'm surprised.

Comment: It's so annoying here that Mathematica deems negative primes to be prime, or else you could save bytes by replacing `PrimeQ[#-2^Range[0,Log2@#]]` with `PrimeQ[#-2^Range[0,#]]` and then by `PrimeQ[#-2^Range@#/2]`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 34 bytes

```
n->n%2*prod(i=0,n,!isprime(n-2^i))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DYpBCoAwDMC@UgWhkw263edTBEEnPdiV6v9nLzkk0cM43ToaVBiSNlnKqtZP5EpR4sSvGj8XSio7hzBaNxR/c4RMRBE8y@dqhrQ5Gkrw7Qc)

Answer (score 4):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 75 bytes

prints 1 for truthy and 0 for falsy

```php
for($t=1&$argn;0<$d=$n=$argn-2**$i++;$d-1?:$t&=0)for(;--$d&&$n%$d;);echo$t;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HctBCoAgFEXReauIeEkaQjbs@3EtkZVNVML9Gzm8B24OuVqXQ@477O8deTAD1Su9Ewob0YwWC8@I3EqvSuGZZ4LXxm0oghf5D6Q1vBCIIzxJOo@QUKjWDw)

[Try it online! Polignac Integers under 10000](https://tio.run/##Jcw9D4IwEAbgvb/CkJNQPhJqXPRoGAyDiy5uxpDGVmApzVEno38dG7jpvbzPnevdXNWudxtmiEZqybiR/GC75Ne0l@vtfGo4MlDUWRmJ/SFC9hrJqGefkLKdSUQuyjBcTQviH/a2k/EJ@BwGjnPQIculjAWWFdh1KXZpCkOWIehC1EfwsSz5orUEi0UBOo7BbkFjeAN@QXR/rNf4ZY4G69vgKfR/)

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
/₂ℕ|>ṗ;?-₍ḃ+1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X/9RU9Ojlqk1dg93Tre2133U1PtwR7O24f//hkYWAA)

[Output de Polignac numbers upto 1000.](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pvaGBg8Gj@supHbRseNTU96lhe83BXZ@3DrRP@64P4LVNr7B7unG5tr/uoqffhjmZtw///AQ)

Returns `false.` for de Polignac numbers and `true.` otherwise.

Based on @LeakyNun's deleted answer, with a few bugfixes (posted with their permission).

*(-2 bytes by using @Jonathan Allan's method to check if the number is a power of two.)*

The given number is not a de Polignac number if:

```
/₂ℕ              It's an even number
   |>ṗ           Or there exists a prime number less than the input
      ;?-₍       which when subtracted from the input
          ḃ      gives a result that has a binary form
           +     such that the sum of the bits 
            1    is 1
```

Comment: `=h2` would be 1 byte shorter but it doesn't work for `3` either.

Comment: Note to (non mobile) self: 14 bytes [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pvaGBg8Gj@supHbRseNTU96lhe83BXZ@3DrRP@64P4LVNr7B7unG5tr/uoqffhjuYkbYP//wE "Brachylog – Try It Online"). Inspired by Jonathan Allan's Jelly answer.

Comment: 13 [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/pvaGBg8Gj@supHbRseNTU96lhe83BXZ@3DrRP@64P4LVNr7B7unG5tr/uoqffhjmZtw///AQ "Brachylog – Try It Online")

Comment: Reminder for your notes i guess?

Comment: @Kroppeb Heh, thanks, I didn't even remember making these comments (while half-asleep, probably).

Comment: (Also, sorry for the delay in response, I've (finally!) moved to an SSD, and so was away from the site for a while setting things back up.)

Comment: This does not work, at least not on TIO. Both the 13 and 15 byte versions identify a list of numbers that bear no resemblance to de Polignac numbers, regardless of whether true/false is inverted.

Comment: @Deadcode It used to be working when this was posted, and something about division seems to have changed in the meantime - for eg. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r/X/9RU9P//4ZGFv@jAA "Brachylog – Try It Online") returns false instead of 64. The change is likely from [this commit](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog/commit/59593ae3ffd4d9ecbf109ba87611137d88f07fef) to the language, but I haven't been active here in a while, so don't know if it's intentional or a bug.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 13 bytes

```
ÆRạl2=Ḟ$o/o‘Ḃ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASMA3P9qZWxsef//w4ZS4bqhbDI94bieJG8vb@KAmOG4gv///zEyNw)

```
ÆRạl2=Ḟ$o/     Main link; argument is z
ÆR             Generate all primes in the range [2..z]
  ạ            Absolute difference with z for each prime
   l2          Logarithm Base 2
     =Ḟ$       For each one, check if it's equal to its floored value (i.e. if it is an integer)
        o/     Reduce by Logical OR to check if any prime plus a power of two equals the z
          o‘Ḃ  Or it's not an odd number. If it's not an odd number, then automatically return 1 (false).
```

Outputs `1` for false and `0` for true.

Comment: `Ḷ2*ạfÆRṆ` then check for parity

Comment: @LeakyNun `Ḷ2*ạfÆRṆo‘Ḃ` returns `1` for both `127` and `22`; that's not right. Unless that's not what you suggested.

Comment: you need to use and, not or. (or you can remove my last negation and then proceed to do it in 9/10 bytes)

Comment: @LeakyNun Your snippet there gives `0` for 149.

Comment: @ETHproductions right. Changing `ạ` to `_@` fixes it.

Comment: This [throws an error for 1](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//w4ZS4bqhbDI94bieJG8vb@KAmOG4gv///zE "Jelly – Try It Online"), which is one of the test cases.

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org/), 55 bytes

```
{so$_%2&&$_∉((1,2,4...*>$_) [X+] grep &is-prime,^$_)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYPu/ujhfJV7VSE1NJf5RR6eGhqGOkY6Jnp6elp1KvKZCdIR2rEJ6UWqBglpmsW5BUWZuqk4cUKL2v7VCcWIlVCpNRyHO1MDA@j8A)

- `(1, 2, 4 ... * > $_)` is a sequence of the powers of two until the input argument (Perl infers the geometric series from the provided elements).
- `grep &is-prime, ^$_` is the list of prime numbers up to the input argument.
- `[X+]` evaluates the sum of all elements of the cross product of the two series.

I could have done without the `so` for two bytes less, but then it returns two distinct falsy values (`0` and `False`).

Answer (score 2):

## Axiom, 86 bytes

```
f(n:PI):Boolean==(~odd?(n)=>false;d:=1;repeat(n<=d or prime?(n-d)=>break;d:=d*2);n<=d)
```

test and results

```
(21) -> for i in 1..600 repeat if f(i) then output i
   1
   127
   149
   251
   331
   337
   373
   509
   599
```

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell, <s>104</s> 102 bytes

```
p x=[x]==[i|i<-[2..x],x`mod`i<1]
h k|even k=1>2|2>1=notElem k$((+)<$>(2^)<$>[0..k])<*>filter(p)[1..k]
```

**Explanation**

- p is a function that finds prime numbers (very inefficient!)
- Creating a list of `(+)` applied to 2^ partial function which is applied to a list [0..input]
- Applying the above to a list filtered 1 to input for primes
- Resulting cartesian product of every possible value is searched to ensure input does not exist in cartesian product
- Guarded to ensure that an even input is automatically false.

UPDATE: Shout out to Einkorn Enchanter for golfing two bytes!

Comment: `p x=[x]==[i|i<-[2..x],x\`mod\`i<1]` is a shorter primality test.

Comment: @EinkornEnchanter Great catch!  You golfed me two bytes!

Comment: You can also do `filter p[1..k]` instead of `filter(p)[1..k]`

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 134 bytes

```lisp
(lambda(x)(flet((p(x)(loop for i from 2 below x always(>(mod x i)0))))(or(evenp x)(do((j 1(* j 2))(m()(p(- x j))))((or(>= j x)m)m)))))
```

Return `NIL` when the argument is a Polignac number, `T` otherwise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY3BDsIwDEN/xdrJRULqdmf/UmgnOrVLtVVsXPj1kXLEuSTys/NIcSsnk0jBJCsiplUyLKqgt9Zif4YFXKSCirl8946H4ZRCJUtb/7MD7iHJjgMu7e69cWQWr2c01qgoK8MrLAUa9kLO6HnBjEG9TKOtV6XnH9vg8abmYbJO0xmNgRdQf2ZXUdF9PDqtb@YX)

Ungolfed:

```lisp
(lambda (n)
  (flet ((prime? (x)                 ; x is prime
           loop for i from 2 below x ; if for i in [2..n-1]
           always (> (mod x i) 0)))  ; is x is not divisible by i
    (or (evenp n)                    ; if n is even is not a Polignac number
        (do ((j 1( * j 2))           ; loop with j = 2^i, i = 0, 1,... 
             (m () (prime? (- n j)))); m = n - 2^i is prime?
            ((or (>= j n)            ; terminate if 2^i ≥ n
                 m)                  ; or if n - 2^i is prime
             m)))))                  ; not a polignac if n - 2^i is prime
```

Answer (score 1):

## [APL (Dyalog Extended)](https://github.com/abrudz/dyalog-apl-extended), 12 bytes

```apl
⍱2∘|⍲0⍭⊢-2*…
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY2xagJxDMb3PkXmwsE/@V/IZS6IToL2BYQ7u0jbwaEFB0EQEU50KDg7lC4i7SP4KHmR63dDvuSX5Etm74ui/pwt3l6K5mPZvNZN3cXhazCJ7ZGlsi7aX4ndeRXtX4r2GvtLIY@x/u7m2Ij2gOXROPab@y3H9gSaTp6gz8PRtJvff5hYjLh0EmXKuQ@jbJk0Oak7WWIyNarAlRl5UgSyOnnPDn9ih1SoGBYWzFm4P15miPY9A5YwsApQS37AfxFS@wc)

Anonymous prefix tacit function. Returns 1 for truthy, 0 for falsy.

Largely based on [ETHProductions' Japt answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/129174/74163).

Thanks to @Adám for helping with golfing my original answer, and for making Dyalog Extended for that matter.

#### How:

```apl
⍱2∘|⍲0⍭⊢-2*…   ⍝ Tacit prefix function; input will be called ⍵
           …    ⍝ Inclusive Range [0..⍵]
         2*     ⍝ 2 to the power of each number in the range
       ⊢-       ⍝ Subtract each from ⍵
     0⍭         ⍝ Non-primality check on each resulting number
    ⍲           ⍝ Logical NAND
 2∘|            ⍝ Mod 2
⍱               ⍝ Not any (bitwise OR reduction, then negated)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 98 bytes

```python
lambda x:not(x%2<1or any((lambda x:x>1and all(x%j for j in range(2,x)))(x-2**i)for i in range(x)))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XcrBCsIwDIDhu0@Ri5CMCWvBy1CfxEvGrGbUdJQesqev3UXB6//961ZeSX0N13uN/J5mBhs1FbSjv7iUgXVD/IrdHOsMHGMbFghtWEAUMuvzgb43IkI7@a4T2lF@uFP9a@480HiANYsWlD6gtOcD)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 14 bytes

```
&%Q2!smP-^2dQl
```

[Try it!](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%26%25Q2%21smP-%5E2dQl&input=128&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=22%0A57%0A3%0A1%0A127%0A149%0A251%0A331%0A337%0A373&debug=0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Julia 0.4](http://julialang.org/), 31 bytes

```julia
n->n%2*!any(ispow2,n-primes(n))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FcpBCoAgAATAe6/YgsBCwTwG9RehBKM20SJ6vdl5Zrt3b7PDhEw1szV9bfkKn8L5GEkVoj/WJNh12Z0RLHEYB611BRTjtVNQooGa0Ui4f1Yrl/wB)

Answer (score 0):

## APL(NARS) 80 chars, 160 bytes

```
∇r←f w;n
r←¯1⋄→0×⍳(w≤0)∨w≥9E9⋄r←0⋄→0×⍳0=2∣w⋄n←r←1
→0×⍳w≤n⋄→3×⍳0πw-n⋄n×←2⋄→2
r←0
∇
```

The function 0π is the function that return its argument is prime or not. For me this function has not be recursive so it is a little more long... Test:

```
  {1=f ⍵:⍵⋄⍬}¨1..1000
1  127  149  251  331  337  373  509  599  701  757  809  877  905  907  959  977  997
```

for input <=0 or input >=9E9 it return ¯1 (error)

```
  f¨0 ¯1 ¯2 900000000001
¯1 ¯1 ¯1 ¯1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [C# (Visual C# Interactive Compiler)](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/about-mono/releases/5.0.0/#csc), 107 bytes

```cs
x=>{var r=Enumerable.Range(2,x);return x%2>0&r.All(p=>r.Any(d=>d<p&p%d<1)|r.All(n=>x!=p+Math.Pow(2,n-2)));}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY7LDoIwFET3fMV1AWnDmy20iQvdmRA/wKRAK03w0hRQjPrtiLp0dyaTzJl6COtBL3EMxs9O6OwnrAuNY1D1fccVW2bGH1dhwbIdThdpRdXJ6CjwLEkWzDS3cpwswuxmPPFstO06YhhfAe@kYbwpjGfcpkjp81ci4/OGGf8gxjYq@9u6gmFGKc1fS@44qrdS1C35KDVohD9rGqRJklDqAGhFFNFfBCjtentN@fIG)

Not the most efficient code, but seems to work. My [original solution](https://tio.run/##ZU@7DoIwFN35iuuAaQOUx4pt4qCbCXFxMymkSBNszQUUUL8dkcnE7TyS8yiaoGj0FIZw85KzcfadKTbatH5ubS1KPvVcPO8SAfnOdFeFMq8VO0pzUSTxe5qiajs00LuJiNbITpVCRQYukG3rmoxcjIIPr8EdRUTpov2a/YoP3kG2FcvsYw4cg4RSmr6n1HFKi0oWFfm2a9AG/gbEfhxFc6wDoEtSEr1AgAznBzNLpw8) filtered for primes before testing them in the formula and it performed much better. The current version is 11 bytes shorter.

```cs
// input x is an integer
x=>{
  // we need to generate several
  // ranges. since this is verbose,
  // generate 1 and keep a reference
  var r=Enumerable.Range(2,x);
  // this is the main condition
  return
     // input must be odd
     x%2>0&
     // generate all possible p's
     // over our range and ensure that
     // they satisfy the following
     r.All(p=>
       // either p is not prime
       r.Any(d=>d<p&p%d<1)
       |
       // or there is no n that satisfies
       // the formula: x=p+2^n
       r.All(n=>x!=p+Math.Pow(2,n-2))
     );
}
```